# tox envlist using any python3 interpreter, exactly once

Tags: python, tox

In my `tox.ini` file I have

```
[tox]
envlist = py27,py33,py34
skip_missing_interpreters = True
```

but I'm really trying to test against one `python3` and not really interested in minor `python3` versions. I'm just trying to support environments in which `python-3.3` is installed but not `python-3.4` and vice versa. This is not convenient because

- the list of intepreters will grow indefinitely
- when multiple interpreters are availables (my laptop has both 3.3 and 3.4) the tests are run multiple times and that takes time

Ideally there would be a way to write:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27,py3
```

in order to select whatever python3 version is installed. I don't think this is possible but maybe there is a workaround ?

Comment: Have you tried it with `envlist = py27,py3`? Although it doesn't seem to be documented, that syntax works for me to run tests with Python 2.7 and Python 3.x (where 3.x is whichever Python version the `python3` command points to, I guess).

Comment: it does work indeed :-)